# Issues with geometricprecision in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, text-rendering

The [website I'm working on](http://tapcore.com/) has issues with how the text is displayed in Google Chrome. I added `text-rendering:geometricprecision` to make it look better, but apparently it caused some text rendering bug. See [this](http://recordit.co/XlFkBVRuUs/) and [this](http://recordit.co/hqOquS1z43/) video. Any ideas on what might be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Adding `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden` solved the issue.